# Is the mode equal to the expected value of the the value of the most frequent sample element?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Can it generally be said that the mode of a discrete distribution is equal to
the value of the most frequent element of a sample of i.i.d. elements of the distribution?

I.e. I take a sample of $N$ i.i.d. random variables distributed $\sim Dist$.
I take $X$ to be defined as value of the most frequent element within the sample.

Can I generally assume that $E[X] = Mode(Dist)$ ?

Comment: No, as a simple example computation should convince you.  You are asking if the expected value of the sample mode equals the population mode.

Comment: The mode of a distribution is not an expected value.  The mean is an expected value. 
 The definition of expected value can be found on Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value.  If you are taking samples from a population, you can develop a confidence interval for the actual mean (or mode) of the distribution.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson I know that the population mode is not an expected value. It doesn't need to be for my question to make sense. I am asking if something else happens to be equal to it.

Comment: @hardmath Well, are there (discrete) distributions for which the expectation of the sample mode is equal to the population mode?

Comment: Right, please keep reading as I have noted that you can develop a confidence interval.  A C.I. will come from your samples as opposed to a 'mean' mode.  There will be a mean mode but it won't be the expected value of the distribution as @hardmath pointed out first thing.

Comment: @GwendolynAnderson Ok, I know how to generate a CI for the mean, given the type and possibly sd of the distribution, but how can the same be done for the mode, unless it is a distribution for which mean=mode?

Comment: Consider a distribution where $P[X = 0] = 49$% and $P[X=1000] = 51$%.  You can see that averaging the values in your samples will not lead to the mode which is $1000.$  From many samples you might assume the mode is $0$.  So how you develop confidence of the mode depends on the distribution and the size of the samples.  The confidence of the mean is based on the Central Limit Theorem.  Such properties do not exist for the mode.

Comment: As a little reflection on @Gwendolyn's example will show, the expected value of sample mode will in general depend on sample size $N$, while the mode of the "population" does not (it is a property of the underlying discrete distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode of a distribution is not an expected value.  Consider the distribution of the random variable $X$ where $P[X = 0] = 40$%, $ P[X=500] = 20$%, and $P[X = 1000] = 40$%. This is clearly a bimodal distribution.  For most samples, depending on the sample size n, the mode will be $0$ or $1000$ with equal likelihood, and for some samples, the mode will be $500$.  Expected value is a mean average, and the mean average of the modes of the samples will tend towards $500$ which is clearly not a mode of this distribution.  To develop a reliable estimate for a mode, it is helpful to know something about the shape of the distribution.  If the mode equals the mean, such as for a normal distribution, then a confidence interval can be developed.  It should be clear from the example that a mean average of sample observations will not be useful in predicting the mode of a distribution that is bimodal or whose mode is very different from the mean, since a mode can not be derived from mean averages.